# Change the format of the axis tick labels in LiveCharts

Tags: c#, winforms, format, axis-labels, livecharts

I just can't find a solution for changing the format of the y-axis tick labels.
Now I get labels like `0.03` and `0.035`. But I always need three digits behind the decimal point. 
The big question is, how to access the label format?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Media;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Helpers;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using LiveCharts.Wpf.Charts.Base;
using Brushes = System.Windows.Media.Brushes;
using Color = System.Windows.Media.Color;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox;

namespace LiveAnalysis
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<DateTime> xvals = new List<DateTime>();
        List<double> yvals = new List<double>();
        private int _amountValues;
        private int _startValue;
        private List<double> _yvalsRange;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // event
            cartesianChart2.DataClick += CartesianChart1OnDataClick;
            hScrollBar1.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => hScrollBar1_ValueChange(sender, e, hScrollBar1.Value);

            // get original data
            using (var db = new Analysis.DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var lttResults = db.LttResults;
                var par1 = 0.0;
                foreach (var data in lttResults)
                {
                    if (data.GatewayEventType == 41)
                        par1 = data.FloatValue;
                    if (data.GatewayEventType != 42) continue;

                    var par2 = data.FloatValue;
                    var diff = Math.Round(par1 - par2, 3);
                    yvals.Add(diff);
                    xvals.Add(data.DateTime);
                }
            }

            // chart settings
            ChartSettings();
        }

        private void ChartSettings()
        {
            // performance
            cartesianChart2.DisableAnimations = true;
            cartesianChart2.DataTooltip = null;
            cartesianChart2.Hoverable = false;

            _startValue = 0;
            _amountValues = 400;
            _yvalsRange = yvals.GetRange(_startValue, _startValue + _amountValues);

            // series setting
            ScatterSeries scatterSeries1 = new ScatterSeries("Series1");
            cartesianChart2.Series.Add(scatterSeries1);
            scatterSeries1.Values = _yvalsRange.AsChartValues();
            scatterSeries1.MaxPointShapeDiameter = 10;
            scatterSeries1.Title = "Series1";

            cartesianChart2.AxisX.Add(new Axis
            {
                Name = "xAxis",
                Title = "DateTime",
                FontSize = 22,
                Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
                MinValue = 0,
                MaxValue = _amountValues,
            });
            cartesianChart2.AxisY.Add(new Axis
            {
                Name = "yAxis",
                Title = "Time difference",
                FontSize = 22,
                Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
                MinValue = -0.025,
                MaxValue = 0.04,
            });
        }

        private void CartesianChart1OnDataClick(object sender, ChartPoint chartPoint)
        {
            label1.Text = $@"You clicked: {chartPoint.X},{chartPoint.Y}";
        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void hScrollBar1_ValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e, int value)
        {
            RedrawGraph(value);
        }

        private void RedrawGraph(int value)
        {
            _startValue = value * 10;
            _yvalsRange = yvals.GetRange(_startValue, _startValue + _amountValues);
            cartesianChart2.Series[0].Values = _yvalsRange.AsChartValues();
            cartesianChart2.AxisX[0].MinValue = _startValue;
            cartesianChart2.AxisX[0].MaxValue = _startValue + _amountValues;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

```
Func<double, string> formatFunc = (x) => string.Format("{0:0.000}", x);

cartesianChart2.AxisY.Add(new Axis
{
    LabelFormatter = formatFunc,
});
```

Comment: Nice, was just going to link the documentation from livecharts, glad you found it!