# How to handle charts directly in code

Tags: c#, livecharts

I started working with C# and Live Charts a few days ago.

Based on examples found in the internet, I made a very simple graph in order to understand the concepts behind it.

That is what I have (it is working perfectly fine):

```
public partial class Wdw_graph : Window
{
    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }

    public Wdw_graph(List<dated_value> serie)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection();

        ColumnSeries col_serie = new ColumnSeries {
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(),
                DataLabels = true };

        Labels = new string[serie.Count];

        for(int i = 0; i < serie.Count; i++)
        {
            col_serie.Values.Add(serie[i].value);
            Labels[i] = serie[i].date;
        }

        SeriesCollection.Add(col_serie);          

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

```xaml
<Grid>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" >
          <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding Labels}" LabelsRotation="80">
              <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                <lvc:Separator IsEnabled="False" Step="1"></lvc:Separator>
              </lvc:Axis.Separator>
            </lvc:Axis>
          </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Sold Apps"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, I have 'SeriesCollection' and 'Labels' handled in the class code and them they are bound to the XAML.

I would like to know if it is possible to use the same approach to handle other graph elements, such as the 'AxisX'. If so, how can I do it?

In this post ["Change the format of the axis tick labels in LiveCharts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976646/change-the-format-of-the-axis-tick-labels-in-livecharts) there is a code that shows what I would like to do:

```
cartesianChart2.AxisX.Add(new Axis
{
    Name = "xAxis",
    Title = "DateTime",
    FontSize = 22,
    Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
    MinValue = 0,
    MaxValue = _amountValues,
});
```

But I could not reproduce that. I can't figure out where the 'cartesianChart2' comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I learned how to refer to the XAML elements in the class code.

I added 'x:Name="something"' to the CartesianChart and removed everything else (not using 'Binding' anymore):

```
<Grid>
    <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="cartesian_chart">
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

Then, in the class code I inserted the axis and serie:

```
public partial class Wdw_graph : Window
{
    public Wdw_graph(List<dated_value> serie)
    {
        InitializeComponent();         

        cartesian_chart.AxisX.Add(new Axis
        {
            Name = "xAxis",
            Title = "Date and Time",
            FontSize = 20,
            Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
            MinValue = 0,
            MaxValue = serie.Count,
            Labels = new String[serie.Count],
        });
        cartesian_chart.AxisY.Add(new Axis
        {
            Name = "yAxis",
            Title = "Currency",
            FontSize = 20,
            Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
            MinValue = 0,
            MaxValue = 10,
        });

        cartesian_chart.AxisX[0].Separator.Step = 1;
        cartesian_chart.AxisX[0].LabelsRotation = 80;

        ColumnSeries col_serie = new ColumnSeries {
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(),
                DataLabels = true };

        for(int i = 0; i < serie.Count; i++)
        {
            col_serie.Values.Add(serie[i].value);
            cartesian_chart.AxisX[0].Labels[i] = serie[i].date;
        }

        cartesian_chart.Series.Add(col_serie);

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

I really preferred to handle the graph directly from the code, instead of using the XAML.

Can you tell me what are the drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: For more complicated layouts, using code can become much easier and hard to understand than XAML. Using XAML for UI/layouts and code for logic helps maintain separation between the two.